# SELECT string expression recognizes single not double quotes?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I'm creating an Azure Stream Analytics query and I needed to output a constant column header/value, and I noticed that if I include a string expression as a `SELECT` item, it needs to be enclosed in single (') not double (") quotes, otherwise I get a NULL.

```
SELECT 'foo' as "bar" INTO ... FROM ... >>> outputs foo as a value of bar.
SELECT "foo" as "bar" INTO ... FROM ... >>> outputs null as a value of bar.
```

Why does a string literal require single quotes? And if I use double quotes, what is it interpreting that literal as?

Thanks

-John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, both single (') and double (") quotes could get the result.

My test json as below:

```
{"plantId": "Plant A", "machineId" : "M001", "sensorId": "S001", "unit": "kg", "time": "2017-09-05T22:00:14.9410000Z", "value": 1234.56}

{"plantId": "Plant A", "machineId" : "M001", "sensorId": "S001", "unit": "kg", "time": "2017-09-05T22:00:19.5410000Z", "value": 1334.76}
```

The result as below:

[image]

---

If you use single quote to select the value, the result will be the single quote's value. The query will not regard the value as the column name to select the result:

Like this:

[image]

But if you use double quote to select the value, the query will regards it as the column name. So you will get the null result. Because the query couldn't select the data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Brando, but what I was looking for was a literal value to be returned in the result. In your example above, had your select read SELECT "foo" as "uarr", I would have expected to see "foo" as the value under the UARR column heading. In other words, this is regardless of the incoming data. I want to place a hard-coded value in the result set that does not come from the data. Based on your test, it looks like if the literal is enclosed in double quotes, it is interpreted as a property name. By my tests, if it is enclosed in single quotes, it is used as a literal value.

Comment: See my update answer. You could use single quota to return a literal value in the result.

Comment: Thanks Brando. You confirmed my test regarding the single quote, but also added the behavior of the double quote. I'll mark this as an answer, but I sure would like to see where this is documented, in case anyone out there knows. I'd like to rely on behavior that I know was actually intended!